# How can I get the accuracy frequency by using DSP

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, matlab-figure

I have a radar signal as picture below.

The orange color is just the reference signal(triangular wave up ramp), and blue line is received baseband signal.
[image]

Cuz this is just a short cut of all received data, if I do the FFT directly I can only get an inaccuracy frequency tone like the img below.(green color)

[image]

So I multiply a phase term in time domain signal then I can get more information from the signal(according to img2 the second and the third subplot)

Now I'd like to know how can I merge three imgs together, then I can get the FFT with more sample points then directly do the FFT.

(should I do the zero padding or something?)
I think this maybe a fundamental DSP problem, but I'm not really sure how to deal with the problem.

Thanks a lots!

Comment: How about running fft on short segments, then average all abs(fourier) transforms? Alternatively, you can use the unaveraged fourier output to plot time frequency results

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz I guess you mean use plot cmd in this way: plot(x_axis1, FFT,x_axis2, FFT_0.5,x_axis3, FFT_0.25), and I got an img like this (https://imgur.com/a/Gc4jkzK) not surprisingly.